# get variable name using character strings that contain "$" in r

Tags: r, dynamic-columns

I want to change the colnames of my dataframe "pre_sub" within a loop. Therefore I need to get access to different columns in my dataframe, which I address with various loop indices (i, j,k)
This is what I have so far:

`colnames(as.name(paste("pre_sub$",variable[i], a_parse[k], sep=""))) <- paste(variable_new[i], frame_name[j], a_parse[k], sep="")`

My problem is that the as.name function now gives me my pasted name in backticks, like so

"backtick" + pre_sub$VA14 + "backtick" (I can't use backticks, as the text is than transformed to code)

And therefore the colname-function doesn't work.

This only appears when I include the "$" sign in my paste function. Do you know how I can get the name of my dataframe-columns without the backticks?

Thanks!